# Circular reference with EF4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, entity-framework-4

I am trying to return an Entity Framework 4 object with children to an jQuery JSON AJAX function but I get a circular reference error - in short my method looks like this

```
[WebMethod]
public static JSONObject Get()
{
  WebHelper.JSONObject lJSONObject = new WebHelper.JSONObject();

  lJSONObject.Object =  Repository.Parent.Include("Child.Child").FirstOrDefault();

  return lJSONObject;
}
```

if I do not include children the functions works fine, but with children the circular reference occurs. Any ideas what I can do to fix this?

Comment: The root of the problem is that JSON cannont handle circular references

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have to return a JSONObject? If not, you can try using [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/), which will handle circular references properly:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                   {
                       ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                   };

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

My guess is that the `JsonObject` is simply a wrapper that will serialize the entity and put it on the response stream, which is simple enough to do manually.

Comment: The JSONObject is my own custom class with a few properties so I on the client can determine what is returned - e.g. i got 2 properties to handle 2 different types of error (Exception and my own custom exception type) - this way I can perform different actions based on the type returned. 

I can easely return another type of object as long as I on the client is able to see if it is Object, typeX or typeY that is returned - will this be possible with the suggested solution?

Comment: Can you update your question with your JSONObject code? I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding how it works based on your comment.

Comment: unfortunately I do not got my code here, but will it be as simple as just writing: object myobject = Repository.Parent.Include("Child.Child").FirstOrDefault(); string myjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myobject, Formatting.Indented, settings); lJSONObject.Object =  myjson; ?

Comment: my class looks something like this - quite simple: public static class JSONObject
{
  public object Object { get; set; }
  public string Exception { get; set; }
  public MyException myException { get; set; }
}

Comment: JSON.NET did the job - I could use it together with my own JSONObject :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding ScriptIgnore attribute to property Parent. See for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx

-- EDIT --

They will be overwritten if you do this in designer file. But you can try adding metadata type:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(TestMD))]
public partial class Test
{
}

public class TestMD
{
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public object Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If I do this I guess my changes will be overwritten everytime I build my model?

Comment: Even with ScriptIgnore on all reference types in my EF entity metadata, I still get circular references on the dynamic proxy object :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Not sure if there's any other solution, but I got it to work creating my own Serialize method.

Comment: Is this a top secret code or is it possible you can give a link, past it in here or something?

Comment: I guess not... but your serialize method should work according to your app. So mine wouldn't be helpful to you. Here's what I did (PS: ScriptIgnore didn't work for me): first I got the pattern used to serialize my object, (in my case I needed to serialize, not add an item as you do, but the principal is the same) but in general should be like {var1:'val1', var2:'val2'} and so on... then, based on that standard you can create your own serialize/"de"serialize method. It's a bit rough, but that's what worked for me and I'm pretty sure Json's serialize work almost the same.